# Pgfplots with 2nd y-axis and "non-linearly" converted units

Tags: pgfplots, fpu

I want to plot a diagram in which I display scattered values within a certain range - these are the maximum values of a measurement I made. From these values, a parameter can be calculated through a formula containing a square root (let's assume `y_2=\sqrt{a \cdot y_1}`). I would like to show a second y-axis `y_2` from which the obtained parameter can directly be read off. I have included an example of what the diagram could look like (created in pyplot).

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way on how I could obtain a second y-axis for a pgfplot that is not "linearly dependent" on the first y-axis. Does anybody have an idea on what I have to do to generate such a graph with pgfplots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add annotations to a plot, to place them according to axis coordinates, to retrieve the axis `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` values, etc. Therefore, with a bit of care due to how `pgfplots` executes code in the `axis` environment (cf. *Utility Commands* in chapter *Utilities and Basic Level Commands* of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)), one can draw this custom secondary scale.

The following code reproduces your plot, where you appear to have used *y*<sub>2</sub> = sqrt(*ay*<sub>1</sub>) with *a* = 5. In order to use this particular function, my code specifies the function and its reciprocal:

```latex
declare function={y2(\x) = sqrt(5*\x);
                  y1(\x) = \x^2/5;}
```

The loop maximum value is automatically determined using the expression given for `y2` and the `ymax` value for the plot. One could do the same to determine the minimum loop value in function of `ymin`, but I prefer manually setting it to `0`, otherwise should you lower `ymin` below 0, you would obtain errors (trying to take the square root of a negative number).

I use the PGF `fpu` library in places where computations are done so that this solution has good chances to work as well with other functions where intermediate results might have a very small or a very large magnitude.

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\newif\ifmyInsideAxis

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=10, clip=false, grid,
             declare function={y2(\x) = sqrt(5*\x);
                               y1(\x) = \x^2/5;},
             ylabel={$y_1$},
             execute at end axis={
  \edef\myYmin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
  \edef\myYmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}
  %
  \begingroup
  \pgfset{fpu=true}
  % Two values given at the start → the pgfmath parser is used.
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,1,...,{int(ceil(y2(\myYmax)))}} {
    \pgfmathparse{y1(#1)} \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}
    \edef\currentY{\pgfmathresult}
    %
    \myInsideAxistrue
    \ifdim \currentY pt>\myYmax pt \myInsideAxisfalse
    \else \ifdim \currentY pt< \myYmin pt \myInsideAxisfalse \fi
    \fi
    %
    \edef\temp{
      \ifmyInsideAxis
        \noexpand\path
          (current axis.east |- 0,0) ++(axis direction cs:0,\currentY)
          coordinate (m);
        \noexpand\draw
          (m) -- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/minor tick length}]m)
          node[font=\noexpand\tiny, right] {\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}};
      \fi
    }
    {\pgfset{fpu=false} \temp}
  } % end of \pgfplotsinvokeforeach's body
  \endgroup
  }]
\addplot[blue, only marks, mark=square*]
  coordinates { (2,5) (3,7) (4,6) (5,9) (6,8.5) };

\node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=2em]current axis.east) {$y_2 = \sqrt{a y_1}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed description - I would have never gotten to that solution myself. I tried your example and it worked great! I surely will need some time to fully grasp what you did there to possibly adapt and tweak your solution, but I suppose that I can take the rest from here! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)